# Use logical Or with thread inside If Statement

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I use multithreading in my program and I want to create a button to check if any of the threads is still running. If there are no threads running in the background, I want the button to do a specific job like run another thread.

I've written the following code on the button:

```
        If thread1 Or thread2 Or thread3   is Nothing Then

        thread2 = New Thread(AddressOf Me.thread2_engine) 
        thread2.Start()

    Else If thread2.IsAlive = True Then

        MsgBox("Processing right now, Please wait")

    End If
```

Why can't I use an `Or` operation inside the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `Or` like that, you are doing a bitwise Or on the variables. I think what you mean is

```
If (thread1 Is Nothing) Or (thread2 Is Nothing) Or (thread3 Is Nothing) Then
```

You might want to use `OrElse` instead of `Or` as that will avoid checking the later conditions once one of them is true.